# Does Teleportation provoke the shaman opportunity action Spirit's Prey?

Tags: dnd-4e, movement, teleportation, shaman

From compendium:

> **Spirit's Prey (Opportunity action)**
>
> Trigger: An enemy leaves a square adjacent to your spirit companion without shifting
>   Target: The triggering enemy
>   Effect: One ally within 10 squares of your spirit companion can make a ranged basic attack against the target as a free action with combat advantage.

Due to the wording in this power, it seems to be an exception to the teleportation rules provoking no opportunity actions (PHB2 p211). The target is leaving the square without shifting. I feel like if the wording was instead "The target leaves a square adjacent to the spirit without shifting or teleporting", a teleport would not provoke. Can someone help clear this up for me, or explain why teleport wording still overrides what to me looks like an exception wording in the Spirit Prey's power?

In the same vein, does forced movement provoke? To me, the wording "leaves a square" sounds voluntary, so forced movement still would not provoke.

Answer (score 13):

From the Rules Compendium, page 212:

> **No Opportunity Actions Triggered:** When a target is pulled, pushed, or slid, it does not trigger opportunity actions, such as opportunity attacks, that are triggered by movement.

From the Rules Compendium, page 214:

> **No Opportunity Actions Triggered:** When a target teleports, it doesn't provoke opportunity actions, such as opportunity attacks, that are triggered by movement.

Nothing in **Spirit's Prey** overrides the default rule by saying that teleportation or forced movement *do* trigger it, therefore the default rule stands and teleportation and forced movement do **not** trigger **Spirit's Prey**.

Comment: The wording had me confused, too. The important thing to remember is that shifting only prevents opportunity attacks, but can still trigger opportunity actions. Since spirit's prey is an opportunity action and not an opportunity attack, it would normally trigger on shifting enemies and thus has to explicitely exclude shifting.